# How to change the language preferences in tesseract from english to others?

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract, training-data

i was able to build a simple ocr application for android sucessfully in english language (using tesseract) by following 
http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/

Now it can recognize English characters . But how can i change the language preferences from english to any other ? ex indic languages

I have downloaded the trained data for an indic language and replaced with english and modified some code accordingly. But it doesnt turn up with results.

Answer (score 1):

The `lang` parameter in the statement `baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);` specifies the language for OCR.

Comment: i have made the lang from eng to hin....but it doesnt turn up with results. it doesnt display even a letter after ocr.

Comment: String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();